# Using proxy with request not working

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, proxy, python-requests

I am trying to scrape a website and I am using Tor module in python to generate proxies and then crawl the website using requests module. But, request module with proxy is identified by the website and returns with a api page (html with message showing some api information). But, when I am using requests without proxy (using my original ip address), I am getting proper response. My question is: How come a website correctly identifies the call from proxy has to be blocked and from original ip (my current ip) has to be accepted.

```
import requests

from stem import Signal
from stem.control import Controller
def renew_connection():
    with Controller.from_port(port=9051) as controller:
        controller.authenticate(password="my_password")
        controller.signal(Signal.NEWNYM)
proxies_http = {
'http': 'http://127.0.0.1:8118'
}
url = 'http://www.websitename.com' #### Not showing real address
page_with_proxy = requests.get(url , headers=random_header , proxies = proxies_http , timeout = 5)

page = requests.get(url , headers=random_header , proxies = None , timeout = 5)
```

Here `page_with_proxy` is having some api information (got to some links and register for api), But `page` (where `proxies == None`) has proper webpage information with all html details (I am able to find all xpaths). Is there any way to bypass this, or how come website easily understand request if using proxy or not?

Answer (score 0):

Many websites either explicitly block access from tor nodes (and other proxy and/or vpn services) or at least require some sort of additional validation. They typically do this by matching the ip address of the request to a list of known tor exit nodes.

There's not really a good workaround, other than simply not passing your requests through a proxy service.

Comment: That means , there is no way by which we could bypass these. No hack or workwrounds.